# Jet Engine not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, jet

I'm trying to debug Delphi application in Delphi 7.

I'm getting error " Jet Engine v3.5 not found

I downloaded and installed Microsoft Jet Engine v 3.5 , but this didn't solve the problem

Please help with error

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to reboot Windows?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the JetEngine and not just Ado? Also installing any version of Office that uses a later JetEngine will by default remove older versions unless you uncheck that options and most people overlook it...

Comment: I rebooted Windows. How I can check JetEngine v 3.5 default for Delphi 7 ?

Comment: It looks like you're using a 3rd party wrapper for DAO, Delphi VCL does not have any 'EDAODatabaseError'. What you're looking for is so old, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167523) if it helps.

Comment: EDAODatabaseError does indeed come from Diamond Access. I didn't spot that before. To check whether you actually have the JetEngine 3.5 installed, look for the `msjet35.dll` in the Windows\System32 folder. You need a lot more than just this single dll, but if that one isn't there, you certainly do not have the JetEngine.

Comment: Hi Marjan , thank you for triyng to help me . I have in Windows\System32 folder both msjet35.dll and msjet40.dll . Maybe this is a problem ? Maybe I need to oblige Delphi to use msjet35.dll ?

Comment: Why do you think you need Jet 3.5? All versions of Windows since Windows 2000 include Jet 4 as part of the OS, and Jet 4 can read/write Jet 3.5 files transparently, so there is really no need for Jet 3.5, unless you've got an app that's hardwired to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Windows are you working?  (XP for the Screen -thanks DR-)
Update the MDAC for your system version. It include all the libraries for use Jet Engine. It's not normal, all the modern operating systems include this libraries.
There are a old utility from Microsoft called [Component Checker](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8f0a8df6-4a21-4b43-bf53-14332ef092c9), execute it to get the version of libraries installed in your system.

You can read the [How to check for MDAC version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301202/en) document, which have some words about it.

Regards.

Comment: The screenshot suggests he's using Windows XP.

Comment: Maybe this error produced by Diamond Access ? I used link to DAODatabase.pas from  Diamond Access during debug.

Comment: I found in DAODatabase.pas from Diamond Access                                                       {$IFDEF SHAREWARE}
  SNagMessage = 'Thank you for EVALUATING Diamond Access.';
{$ENDIF}
  SJetNotFound = 'Jet Engine v.%s not found.';

Comment: Hola Neftalí, hice algunos pequeños cambios en tus enlaces, además de cambiar el último por su versión en Inglés, es realmente un gusto verte por aquí ;)

Comment: Most MDAC version do not include the JetEngine. I think only MDAC 2.5 or 2.6 did. Possibly MS did that to make life harder for users of components such as Diamond Access, as it made it possible to use the MS Access database engine without ever buying MS Access.

Comment: @jachguate; Gracias por los Cambios. Un placer tambien para mi.

Comment: The MDAC excludes Jet because it's installed as part of the OS, starting with Windows 2000. But it's Jet 4.0, not Jet 3.5. However, Jet 4 can transparently read/write Jet 3.5 data.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton , I'd like to avoid annoying error during debugging . Program is working OK after compilation

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use Jet 4, which is installed by default on every copy of Windows beginning with Windows 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can check these two articles from MSDN:

[How To Ensure Jet 3.5 Is Installed Correctly (Part I)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240377/EN-US)
[How To Ensure Jet 3.5 Is Installed Correctly (Part II)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245524/en-us)

Regards.